# drupal check if checkbox field is checked

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to see if a CCK checkbox field is checked.

Is it something like:

```
if ($node->field_checkbox[0]['value'] = 'checked')
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily check the contents of an object (e.g. `$node`) by installing the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and using `dsm($node)`.

In the case of a CCK checkbox, `$node->field_fieldname` contains an array with at least one element. Each element corresponds to each checked checkbox for the field, and the `value` key for the checkbox's element is set to the value you specified in the configuration for the field.

Otherwise, if the checkbox is unchecked, it will not appear as an element within `$node->field_fieldname`.

However, if there are no checkboxes checked, `$node->field_fieldname` will still contain one element, but the `value` key for that element will be unset/set to `NULL`.

So, let's say you had a field, `field_checkbox`, with two checkboxes: 1) *Foo* which has a value of `foovalue`, and 2) *Bar* which has a value of `barvalue`.

To check if *Foo* is checked, you might do:

```
foreach ($node->field_checkbox as $checkbox) {
  if ($checkbox['value'] == 'foovalue') {
     return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: If don't want to use devel module, print structure via print_r($node->field_checkbox);